# How can I pass the data selected from UI-Select to a Tags-Input?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-tags-input

I would like to send the data from the UI-Select to the Tags-Input.
For instance, if I select a value from the UI-Select, then hope the Tags-Input receives it with NG-MODEL.

Here is the code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="member.selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select....">{{$select.selected.member_name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="member in members | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="member.member_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small ng-bind-html="member.member_email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>    
</ui-select>

<tags-input ng-model="{{$select.selected.member_name}}">
</tags-input>
```

I thought putting {{$select.selected.member_name}} in the ng-model in tags-input would be working, but it receives nothing.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Please help me!

Comment: The tags input should be like `<tags-input ng-model="selected.member_name">
</tags-input>`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried but it did not work. I tried {{selected.member_name}} or even {{selected.member.member_name}} as well. Could you help me?

Comment: can you share a JSFiddle with the issue, it will be easier to debug, just minimal code highlighting the issue.

Comment: @Naren, I created the JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/dbj0729/ebkgdude/5/ , but I guess I am missing something as it is my first time using it. I posted the codes. Hope this works out. Look forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on new requirement for multiple selection, please check the below fiddle.

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jhrqchfu/)

For this requirement you dont even need the directive, since anyway the output of ui-select is an array and ng-tags-input also expects and array so there is no problem for multiselection.

**First Answer:**

Sorry for the late reply, the problem with your code was that `<tags-input>` needs to have the same `ng-model` as `<ui-select>`, but there is a catch, ng-tags-input elements expects a list. So my solution for this problem is to add [`parsers`](https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html) to convert the ng-model into a list, then we need to configure the `ng-tags-input` to take the display property as member_name and key property as member_email like so.

`<tags-input ng-model="member.selected" display-property="member_name" key-property="member_email"></tags-input>`

Please find below a fiddle with the working example.

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/w8crfh63/2/)

Also the directive that does the parsing will look like this.

```
app.directive('formatModel', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
                return [value];
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank  you very very very much for your support! I found it fascinating! Really appreciated! I just have a question though: How can I continue adding items from the UI-Select? If I select the other item from the select options, then the first one disappears. Still, I really thank you for your work and JSFiddle! :)

Comment: @Jay You're welcome, I have updated my answer for the new requirement.

Comment: thank you once again! Not only I solved the problem, but also well acknowledged! Thanks many :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem in $select scope lives only inside the ui-select tag so you need to cahnge the model name as $select is undefined in tag-input so try removing $select and try it.

```
<tags-input ng-model="{{selected.member_name}}"></tags-input>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried but it did not work. I tried {{selected.member_name}} or even {{selected.member.member_name}} as well. Could you help me?

Comment: can you send me a plunkr so that i can have a look at it

Comment: @Jay try using ng-model="selected.member_name" remove the ''{{" "}}'' and give  me a feedback if this doesnt work send me a plunkr

Comment: try this fiddle i have used input instead of tag-input try it it will work out  http://jsfiddle.net/vignesh230794/Lv9mo66a/595/

Comment: Thank you Vignesh for the JSFiddle! It was very comprehensive! How all goes well with you!.